# Windows phone 8.1 POST x-www-form-urlencoded not working

Tags: c#, post, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, http-post

I'm trying to send POST x-www-form-urlencoded request payway payment api in C#.

This is my code:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(url));
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> bla = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
bla.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id_number","2000"));
request.Content = new HttpStringContent(new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(bla).ToString(),Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Api returns me status code 100 which stands for "wrong id_number".

I also tried to send POST via Postman and there works fine.

```
POST /services/test HTTP/1.1
Host: example.tk
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c67b2ee3-6e25-7ecc-61f5-38282c23sds7d
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

id_number=2000
```

Can someone know what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NavigateToString("") and add html form inside and post it :D